# Neo blockchain: RPC call for transaction listing

Tags: blockchain, rpc

What is the RPC call to list all transactions of a node? Specific to address or asset

Answer (score 1):

In neo-cli there is no RPC method to get the transactions list with wallet account parameter. You could query the Neoscan API: https://neoscan.io/docs/index.html#api-v1-get-8